# can any body help me in validating the working of my function in a linked list C#. I'm new to this

Tags: c#, linked-list

I'm trying to pass the values of a Student class in a linked but the functions somehow are not working right. A particular function will be executed once and will not move to the other function.

// this class is implementing the functions

```
namespace ListAssignment
{ 
    public class Node
     {
          public Node next;                                    // reference for the next node         
    private Student s;                                   //object for student class

    public Node(String name, int age, int manummer, double grade)
        {
            s = new Student(name, age, manummer, grade);
            next = null;
        }

    internal Student S { get => s; set => s = value; }
}

    public class List
    {
        public Node headstudent= null;                                 //student1, list is initially empty
        public Node current;
        public Node previous;
        public int count;

    public List()
    {
        headstudent = null;
        current = null;
        previous = null;
    }

    public void Push(String name, int age, int manummer, double grade)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node(name, age, manummer, grade);
        newnode.next = headstudent;
        headstudent = newnode;
        count++;
    }

    public void PrintList()
        {
            Node ptr = headstudent;
            if (ptr.next != null)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("details");
                Console.WriteLine(ptr.S.Name + ptr.S.Age + ptr.S.MatriculationNumber + ptr.S.Grade);
                Console.ReadLine();
                ptr = ptr.next;
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("the list is empty");
        count++;
        }

    public void AddAtEnd(String name, int age, int manummer, double grade)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node(name, age, manummer, grade);
        if (headstudent == null)
        {
            headstudent = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            current = headstudent;
            while (current != null)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            previous.next = newnode;
        }
    }

    public void AddAtStart(String name, int age, int manummer, double grade)
        {        
               if (headstudent == null)
            {
            headstudent = new Node(name, age, manummer, grade);
            }
            else
            {
            current = new Node(name, age, manummer, grade);
            current.next = headstudent;
            count++;
            }         
    }

    public object RemoveFirst()
    {
         if (count > 0)
                {
                    headstudent.next = headstudent.next.next;
                    count--;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("list is empty");
                }
                return headstudent;
       }

    public void Replace(int manummer)
    {
        current = headstudent;
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.S.MatriculationNumber == manummer)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("repalce by another number");
                current.S.MatriculationNumber = manummer;
                current = current.next;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter other no.");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

}

// in the replace function I'm trying to replace existing value with a new integer value. I'm trying to directly pass the values in the functions. For reference, I'm also adding the output.

Comment: Is it required from you to implement the `List` class yourself? Because you can use an already exist `List` class in .NET.

Comment: @BassemAkl yes, I'm implementing it from scratch.

Comment: Correct me if I miss something, but your "l.PrintList()" isn't iterated in any way, you just print the head for once. Try using while and not if?

Comment: @BassemAkl if possible can you correct my print function...

Comment: @R2D2, sure. See my edited answer!

Comment: @BassemAkl thanks for your inputs! can you validate my other functions?

Comment: @R2D2, check my edited answer! Note I updated `PrintList` again?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @BassemAkl thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Start using the debugger; Put breaking points and use both Watch and Output windows. See this picture:

[image: Using the Debugger]
For a quick look, I found several mistakes:

1. The `PrintList` Method does not have a loop to print all `Node`s. But it prints only the first `Node`.
2. The `count` does not incremented each time you add a `Node`. To do that: Increment the `count` at the top of all two Methods: `AddAtStart` and `AddAtEnd` and set it to equal one at `Push`. And remove it from all elsewhere.
3. `AddAtStart` does not set the `headstudent` to the new `Node` at the end of the Method.

Also, there are some shortcuts you can use like getting rid of `Student` constructor.

**[Edit]**: Adding code.

```
    public void Push(String name, int age, int manummer, double grade)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node(name, age, manummer, grade);
        current = headstudent = newnode;

        count = 1;
    }

    public void PrintList()
    {
        if (headstudent == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the list is empty");
            return;
        }

        Node ptr = headstudent;
        while (ptr != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ptr.S.Name + " " + ptr.S.Age + " " + ptr.S.MatriculationNumber + " " + ptr.S.Grade);
            ptr = ptr.next;
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

        // remove these lines:
        //else
        //    Console.WriteLine("the list is empty");

        // You should not increment count here anyway!
        //count++;
    }

    public void AddAtEnd(String name, int age, int manummer, double grade)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node(name, age, manummer, grade);

        if (headstudent == null)
            headstudent = newnode;
        else
        {
            current = headstudent;
            while (current != null)
            {
                previous = current;
                current = current.next;
            }
            previous.next = newnode;        // try current =
        }

        count++;
    }

    public void AddAtStart(String name, int age, int manummer, double grade)
    {
        Node newnode = new Node(name, age, manummer, grade);

        if (headstudent == null)
            current = headstudent = newnode;
        else
        {
            current = newnode;
            current.next = headstudent;
            headstudent = newnode;
        }

        count++;
    }

    public void RemoveFirst()
    {
        if (count > 0)
        {
            headstudent = headstudent.next;
            count--;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("list is empty");
        }
    }

    public void Replace(int manummer, int newNumber)
    {
        current = headstudent;
        while (current != null)
        {
            if (current.S.MatriculationNumber == manummer)
            {
                current.S.MatriculationNumber = newNumber;
                Console.WriteLine(manummer + " is replaced by: " + newNumber);
                break;
            }
            current = current.next;
        }
    }
```